# Regex to search file for exact string

Tags: python, regex

I have looked at the other questions around this, but I can't quite get those answers to work for my situation.

I have a string that I'm searching for inside a file.  I want to match the exact string and if there's a match, do something.  I'm trying to formulate regex for the string, "author:".  If this string is found, strip it from the line and give me everything to the right of it, removing any whites space. Any ideas looking at the code below in how to achieve this?.

```
metadata_author = re.compile(r'\bauthor:\b')
with open(tempfile, encoding='latin-1') as search:
    for line in search:
        result = metadata_author.search(line)
        if result in line:
            author = result.strip()
            print(author)
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: …but a potential problem is that there's not necessarily a word boundary after the colon.

Comment: play around in http://www.regexpal.com/ -- it's pretty handy!

Comment: I suspect the problem is `if result in line:`... Why would there be a regex match object in a string? But of course it could also be the syntax error at `for line search:`... Or the `result.strip()`...

Comment: Use `metadata_author = re.compile(r'\bauthor:(.*)')` -> `m = metadata_author.search(line)` -> `if m: author = m.group(1).strip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (with a negative lookbehind for the possible dot as mentioned in the comment):

```
metadata_author = re.compile(r'(?<=(?<!\.)\bauthor:).+')
with open(tempfile, encoding='latin-1') as search:
    for line in search:
        result = metadata_author.search(line)
        if result:
            author = result.group().strip()
            print(author)
```

`re.search` returns a match object, and not a string, so to get the matching string you have to call `result.group()`.

If you want to remove all whitespace (instead of just trimming), use `re.sub(r'\s*', '', result.group())` instead of `result.group().strip()`.

Comment: This is not working for me.  When I try to `print(result)` I get `None` and when I try to `print(author)`, nothing prints.  I originally didn't use regex, but in this file there's a line with 'author:' and a line with 'new.author:' .  I was getting match for both, but I only need the value to the right of 'author:'

Comment: I edited the regex to take into account the 'new.author' case. However, it should have printed both, so I don't know why it doesn't work for you at all (I tried this with a file and it works fine). Could you give an example of the text by pasting what `print(line)´ outputs where there should be a match?

Comment: With your update, this solution now works.  For some reason, it wasn't catching the value the first time.